# How to transfer successfully a parameter from dropdown list to a php file?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap dropdown list and when the end user select one of the items I want to pass the parameter `option` indicated on the `href` attribute to my php file `rssnews.inc.php`, my dropdown list look like:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Select<span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="rubChoice">
        <li><a href="/rss/core/inc/rssnews.inc.php?option=sport" id="act1" data-item="Sport">Sport</a></li>
        <li><a href="/rss/core/inc/rssnews.inc.php?option=politique" id="act2"  data-item="Politique">Politique</a></li>
        <li><a href="/rss/core/inc/rssnews.inc.php?option=international" id="act3"  data-item="International">International</a></li>
        <li><a href="/rss/core/inc/rssnews.inc.php?option=divers" id="act4"  data-item="Divers">Divers</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

my `rssnews.inc.php` file look like:

```
    function getFeed() 
    {
        if (isset($_POST['option'])) {
            $option = $_POST['option'];

            switch ($option) {
                case "sport":
                    $url = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/GalerieArtciles';
                    echo 'Du sport'.$url;
                    break;
                case "international":
                    $url = 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int#';
                    echo 'Du international'.$url;
                    break;
                case "politique":
                    $url = 'http://www.elkhabar.com/feeds/';
                    echo 'du politique'.$url;
                    break;
                default: $url = 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int#';
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            echo "there is error"; 
        }

       $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = simplexml_load_string($content);
    $articles= array();

    foreach( $data->channel->item as $item){

        $articles[]=array(
            'title'         =>  (string)$item->title,
            'description'   =>  (string)$item->description,
            'link'          =>  (string)$item->link,
            'Date'          =>  (string)$item->pubDate,
        );
    }

     $articalesArr = array();
    foreach($articles as $article){
        array_push($articalesArr, $article['title']);    
    }

    return json_encode($articles);
}
if(isset($_GET['function']) && $_GET['function'] !=''){

    $result = $_GET['function']();
    echo json_encode($result);
    header("Content-type:application/json");
} 
    }
```

To execute this function I have a button with `id="start"` and when end user click on it make an AJAX call:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success col-xs-3" id="start"> <i class="fa fa-play"></i>Start</button>
```

the AJAX call:

```
$('#start').click(function(){
            var $item = $('#test');
                $.ajax({
                    type:'GET',
                    url: '/rss/core/inc/rssnews.inc.php?function=getFeed',
                    //dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data){
                    var articles = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $.each (articles, function (key, value) { 
                        $item.append('<div id="item" style="border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc; padding-top:10px; padding-right: 10px;"><ul><li><h4>'+ value.title +'</h4></li> <li>'+ value.description+'</li><li><a href="'+value.link+'">Lire+</a></li></ul>');
                        console.log('success',data);

                    });

                    }
                });
            });
```

Once I execute the code, I get this message `"there is error"`. So, How can I transfer successfully a parameter from dropdown list to a php file ? Knowing that the scenario I follow is: 
1. End user select a topic with dropdown list
2. the topic choosen correspond to a URL 
3. function getFeed() fetch the rss feed
4. when end user click on start button rss is fetched and data displayed on a div element
Any Help I appreciate it.

Comment: Either change it to a select or use javascript to to catch a click

Comment: @Mihai If he is going to use JavaScript, then he should be using AJAX, too. I do no think this person is ready for that.  I would use a `<form>` (method="post"), `<select>`, and multiple `<option>` tags. The heck with Bootstrap if it is interfering with web fundamentals. URL query string parameters are found in $_GET. Sanitize and validate your inputs!

Comment: @I. degollado I edit the description bro

Comment: You are not using POST, you are using GET.  So, any variables in your rssnews.inc.php should be referenced via GET['variablename'].
Second, jquery ajax 'success' has been deprecated, use 'done'
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
Third, add a fail function, right after the success function and do a console.log of the data returned.  That will give you a more detailed error message.
If you have access to your PHP log, you could get more info out of there.
Finally, you are not passing the variable from the drop down (sport,politique,etc) anywhere.  Look at the URL above for an example

Comment: @HA KiM's Why the url `/rss/core/inc/rssnews.inc.php?function=getFeed` is different from anchor link in `<a>` tag? I think you have to change the url in your AJAX call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated my answer since you edited your question...

This is working now:

rssnews.inc.php

```
function getFeed()
{

    if (isset($_POST['option'])) {
        $option = $_POST['option'];

        // dont echo strings here since you want to output json at the end
        switch ($option) {
            case "sport": // this is case sensitive. Your dta-item attributes had capital letter
                $url = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/GalerieArtciles';
                //echo 'Du sport'.$url; 
                break;
            case "international":
                $url = 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int#';
                //echo 'Du international'.$url;
                break;
            case "politique":
                $url = 'http://www.elkhabar.com/feeds/';
                //echo 'du politique'.$url;
                break;
            default: $url = 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int#';
                break;
        }
    } else {
        echo "there is error";
    }

    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = simplexml_load_string($content);
    $articles= array();

    foreach( $data->channel->item as $item){

        $articles[]=array(
            'title'         =>  (string)$item->title,
            'description'   =>  (string)$item->description,
            'link'          =>  (string)$item->link,
            'Date'          =>  (string)$item->pubDate,
        );
    }

    $articalesArr = array();
    foreach($articles as $article){
        array_push($articalesArr, $article['title']);
    }

    return json_encode($articles);
}
if(isset($_GET['function']) && $_GET['function'] !=''){

    $result = $_GET['function']();
    header("Content-type:application/json"); // this one must be called before echoing
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

HTML + Javascript code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Select<span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="rubChoice">
        <li><a role="button" id="act1" data-item="sport">Sport</a></li> 
        <!-- a link is a link, if you click it, it will open url. So remove href and add role="button" to keep it valid html -->
        <li><a role="button" id="act2"  data-item="politique">Politique</a></li>
        <li><a role="button" id="act3"  data-item="international">International</a></li>
        <li><a role="button" id="act4"  data-item="divers">Divers</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="test">

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#rubChoice li').click(function(event){ // more convenient to take the list item as selector

            event.preventDefault(); // prevent link opening

            var $item = $('#test');
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST', // change to post
                url: './rssnews.inc.php?function=getFeed',
                dataType: 'json', // you're expecting json...
                data: {"option":$(this).find('a').attr('data-item')},
                success: function (data){
                    var articles = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $.each (articles, function (key, value) {
                        $item.append('<div id="item" style="border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc; padding-top:10px; padding-right: 10px;"><ul><li><h4>'+ value.title +'</h4></li> <li>'+ value.description+'</li><li><a href="'+value.link+'">Lire+</a></li></ul>');
                        console.log('success',data);

                    });

                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still display to me: "there is error"

Comment: You can use anything you want. It does not have to be POST. It does not have to be a `<form>`. That being said, I would use a HTML form and POST.

Comment: I have tested the code and it works fine. NB you are echoing "there is error" by default.

Comment: @Yolo really !! how was that ?

Comment: well that was the old version of your question.. i fixed up your code and commented what went wrong.

Comment: Just one point, I want to make the change event without reload the page, how can I do so ?

Comment: Are you using a form with a submit button?

Answer (score 0):

use GET method instead POST :

```
if(isset($_GET['option']))
{
    $option = $_GET['option'];
    ...
}
```

Comment: I've tried that but it still show me the same error

Comment: Are you calling the function in some place?

Comment: I can't see any AJAX call in you description.